# How to change position of rowsidecolors in R heatmap.2

Tags: r, heatmap, gplots

When using the R `heatmap.2` function from the `gplots` package, one can pass the argument `rowsidecolors`, which will then insert a column next to the dendrogram [**as shown here**](http://manuals.bioinformatics.ucr.edu/home/R_BioCondManual/hclust3.png). I was wondering if it is possible to relocate the column to the opposite side of the heatmap next to the row labels?

Answer (score 3):

This is about as close as you are going to get to default:

```
lmat=rbind(c(5,0,4), c(3,1,2))
lhei=c(1.5,4)
lwid=c(1.5,0.25,4)
```

New numbering is:

2. Heatmap,

3. Row dendrogram,

4. Column dendrogram,

5. Key,

1. Horizontal Bar

The maintainers should have kept the same numbers and just add 5. for the Horizontal bar but hey let's make it more confusing for fun :)  Basically they put it in a 'queue' LIFO.  Set horizontal bar to 1 and move every thing else down 1.

Answer (score 2):

Read "help(heatmap.2)" about what happens to the 4 plot components when "RowSideColors" is used.  See [Moving color key in R heatmap.2 (function of gplots package)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351575/moving-color-key-in-r-heatmap-2-function-of-gplots-package) for a good explanation of how to control their locations.

Try this:

```
heatmap.2 ( 
    matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10),
    lmat=rbind(c(0,5,4,0,0), c(0,3,2,1,0)), 
    lhei=c(2,5),
    lwid=c(1,1,4,0.25,1),
    col=colorpanel(20, "blue", "black", "red"),
    key = F, trace = "none", scale = "row",
    RowSideColors = rainbow(10)
)
```

Comment: the change to the layout is not in the help function.