# how to place the colokey on the right and make it bigger in heatmap.2?

Tags: r, heatmap, color-key

I'm using heatmap.2 to obtain a triangular heatmap (where the upper part of the matrix is deleted).

I used this code:
    `my_data_t <- t( as.matrix(my_data) )`

```
`cor.matrix <- cor( my_data_t, method = "spearman")`

`cor.matrix[upper.tri( cor.matrix )] <- NA`

`my.col <- c( "blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "red" )`

`my.breaks <- c( 0, 0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 1 )`

`hm2 <- heatmap.2( cor.matrix, scale="none", Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, 
                  col=my.col, breaks=my.breaks, margins(5,5),
                  cexRow=0.5,cexCol=1.0,key=TRUE,keysize=1.5, 
                  trace="none")`
```

my_data was something like this:
    `my_data <- "Taxon  NO8.4   NO6.1   NO7.3   NO9.4   N09.7
                 a  0.1 0.05    0.01    0.2 0.06
                 b  0.0 0.8 0.8 0.0 0.0
                 c  0.7 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1
                 d  0.0 0.01    0.08    0.0 0.09
                 e  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
                 f  0.09    0.05    0.01    0.04    0.0
                 g  0.07    0.7 0.0 0.01    0.08"`

Now I'd like to have the color key on the right of the heatmap and I'd like tomake it bigger (as a bar on the right of the heatmap, as long as this one).
Is it possile in the `heatmap.2` function??

I also tried to use the `legend()` command, but it seems to me that it can generate only box legends, with one box for each color, so no an unique side bar, right??

Comment: As you might recall from yesterday, you were asked to provide a [minimal, reproducible data set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) together with the code you have tried. The same kind request applies today. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry... but I didn't find how to upload files...

Answer (score 0):

See the answer here:
[Moving color key in R heatmap.2 (function of gplots package)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351575/moving-color-key-in-r-heatmap-2-function-of-gplots-package/15364642#15364642)

Unfortunately, what you won't be able to do is rotate the key, which would seem like something you would want to do in this situation.